# How to reset a page number in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I create a report using SSRS reports to show many different kind of information, I use a multiple headers and many tablix that will be used for each page on report.

My page number is not based on group (I use the page number generated by SSRS because I use to put it in the header).

My problem is how to reset a number page for each header.

Answer (score 4):

There are (at least) two options:

1. The first uses page names, described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/04/25/report-design-reset-page-number-on-group.aspx).
2. The other involves subtracting an offset from the buildin function, described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2006/01/05/resetpagenumberongroup.aspx).