# How to display Page Number and Total Pages in SSRS 2016 with specific format like (page # 2 / 5 pages)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

How to display Page Number and Total Pages in SSRS 2016 with specific format like (page # 2 / 5 pages)?

Right Answer (Worked with me)

```
="page # "+Globals!PageNumber.ToString() +" / " + Globals!TotalPages.ToString()+ " pages"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863194/how-to-reset-a-page-number-in-ssrs-report  or https://stackoverflow.com/q/24198336/2033717

Comment: simple. Type the exact same question into Google search box. Click on the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/display-page-numbers-or-other-report-properties-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I tried this expression and found it works well.

```
="page # "+Globals!PageNumber.ToString() +" / " + Globals!TotalPages.ToString()+ " pages"
```